# Want to pass in a string array into a WS.sendRequest using groovy

Tags: arrays, api, groovy, katalon-studio, katalon

I am new to API testing and am using Katalon to develop the tests.  I've Googled any question I could think of and couldn't find anything to answer my question.

We have an API with the following Body

```
[
    "${idValue1}",
    "${idValue2}",
    "${idValue3}",
    "${idValue4}",
    "${idValue5}",
]
```

I believe the purpose of this one is to delete multiple records at once by id.  The script that we have in the step definition is

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('EquipmentAPI/data-objects/DELETE Equipment By Ids', [('host') : GlobalVariable.host, ('idValues') : GlobalVariable.equipId]))

GlobalVariable.equipId = WS.getElementPropertyValue(response, 'data[0].id')
```

There are other step definitions that run before this one to set the Global Variables for use.  I was able to generate the string array without issue.

Is this something that's possible?  Please help!

Please let me know if further information is needed.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: That's ok.  I finally found a way to do what I needed to do without using an array yesterday.  I would love to use an array though.  Basically what I'm trying to do is pass in a list of ids into an API call that will delete records using that list of ids.  I'm using the findTestObject function in Katalon.  But again, it's alright.  I found a way to do it.